# The difference in pronunciation between 'row' and 'roll'

Tags: pronunciation

I see the difference is the 'l' sound, but in practice, they seem to be identical to my ear. How do native speakers distinguish these two words? Or it has to rely on the context?

Comment: What language does your ear normally hear? And do these sounds exist in your language?

Comment: Native speakers of English pronounce those words differently. As Italian, I would not get confused from those words.

Comment: Homophones are far common in my mother language. We have to rely on contexts all the time. I feel English is much better, and just a few words sound similar occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Context, context, context!

Sometimes it's hard to understand what a person is saying with a LOT of context.

An individual word, can be impossible to identify without context.

Of course, if everyone spoke with exactly the same accent, and *took the time* to carefully pronounce each syllable, then it would be a lot easier to identify each word, however that doesn't happen in the real world except maybe for television shows for young children.

*Good luck with that!*

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a big problem here. I can always distinguish these two words if the speaker pronounces them correctly. The word "**row**" has a clear **[ʊ]** sound whereas the word "**roll**" has a clear **[l]** at the end.

Yes, there may be difficult, especially if the word "**roll**" is pronounced as in UK - **[rəʊl]**, which is probably the same as in the word "**role**" but the context can help you distinguish the word used.

Maybe you wanted to ask about distinguishing "**role**" and "**roll**"? If so, then see p.2 for clarity.